# Programming Terminology

Tags: terminology

A long time ago, my college professor defined a term which meant the number of source lines  between a variable definition and its usage.

The lesson basically argued that the closer the two values are, the easier it will be to maintain over the long run.

My Google-Fu has been weak.

What is the term that describes this relationship?

Comment: Variable definition to first use ratio?

Comment: When you find out, tell me. I didn't know we needed a term for this. Maybe your professor needs to find better things to do with his time.

Comment: You can call it *n* for now ;) Seriously though, if there's a word for this I would like to know it.

Comment: Interesting concept. Typically I declare a variable at the time of usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this concept for the first time whilst reading [Code Complete 2](http://www.cc2e.com/).

I think the term you're looking for is 'span' in that book, which is explicitly the number of lines between references to a variable. In my interpretation, a variable declared and used on consecutive lines would have a span of 0.

The concept is reusable for other references to the variable too to give a wider measure of maintainability - the span between declaration and first use may be 0, but if the variable is then used again 100 lines later that's still pretty nasty.

Comment: All of these things are related, but not what OP is asking for

Comment: Yep, page 305.
Thank you Brabster

Answer (score 4):

Found on this page http://www.ppig.org/papers/11th-douce.pdf , on page 6 of the document it talks about `Object Relation Measure`, or `ORM`, and gives the definition and way to calculate it.  I think this is what you might be looking for.

---

is it Code spatial complexity ?